# JSON Extraction from Splunk log

Tags: json, regex, splunk, splunk-query, rex

I have a requirement where i need to extract part of JSON code from splunk log and assign that field to spath for further results

My regex is working in regex101 but not in splunk

below is log snippet --looking to grab the JSON code starting from {"unique_appcodes to end of line..i have shown the expected output below in the post

```
 cwmessage: 2021-08-26 17:14:10 araeapp INFO MRC: Unique AppCodes Report requested.
2021-08-26 17:14:10 araeapp INFO MRC_ARAE_I_042: (local) requesting uniq_appcodes report for KKA
2021-08-26 17:14:10 araeapp INFO {"unique_appcodes": [{"count": 2, "app_code": "XYZ", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 2, "app_code": "QQQ", "group": "TSR05441", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 1, "app_code": "QQQ", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 192, "app_code": "PPP", "group": "TSR05560", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 12, "app_code": "PPP", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 12, "app_code": "GM9", "group": "TSR06083", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 139, "app_code": "ZZZ", "group": "TSR06103", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 6, "app_code": "GNA", "group": "TSR06085", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 803, "app_code": "SSS", "group": "MXXX0718", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 3, "app_code": "SSS", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}]}
```

Rex using:

```
| rex field=_raw (?msi)(?<json_field>\{\"unique_appcodes\".+\}$)
```

and this perfectly working in regex101.com which is extracting  the below required part but when i use this in SPlunk its not giving any results im thinking its the spaces between the JSON attributes

Please let me know your thoughts

```
{"unique_appcodes": [{"count": 2, "app_code": "XYZ", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 2, "app_code": "QQQ", "group": "TSR05441", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 1, "app_code": "QQQ", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 192, "app_code": "PPP", "group": "TSR05560", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 12, "app_code": "PPP", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 12, "app_code": "GM9", "group": "TSR06083", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 139, "app_code": "ZZZ", "group": "TSR06103", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 6, "app_code": "GNA", "group": "TSR06085", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 803, "app_code": "SSS", "group": "MXXX0718", "instance": "KKA"}, {"count": 3, "app_code": "SSS", "group": "", "instance": "KKA"}]}
```

Comment: it might be that you have to use multi-line match, by default it will look only on first line.

Comment: @kaza Not sure what you mean sorry

Answer (score 0):

First, the regex must be enclosed in quotation marks.  The embedded quotes must be triple-escaped (`\{\\\"unique_appcodes`).

Second, the flags are not helpful in Splunk regex.

I've had better luck matching all characters using `[\s\S]+` than with using `.+`.

Comment: | rex field=_raw "(?msi)(?<json_field>\{\"unique_appcodes\"[\s\S]+\}$)"

updated this still no luck  any leads?